# `org-agenda-get-day-entries` errors with "Selecting deleted buffer"

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm attempting to gather entries that were scheduled in the past week, similarly to what org-agenda does.  Following `org-agenda-list`, I defined the following:

```
(defun weekly-status/get-week-days ()
"Return a list of days for the past week suitable for passing to `org-agenda-get-day-entries."
  (let* ((today (org-today))
         (day-list (list today)))
    (dotimes (n (1- 7) day-list)
      (push (1- (car day-list)) day-list))))
```

However, executing the follwing results in "Selecting deleted buffer":

```
ELISP> (let ((this-week-days (weekly-status/get-week-days)))
      (setq this-week-plan-items nil)
      (dolist (day this-week-days this-week-plan-items)
        (let ((date (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute day)))
          (message (format "%s" date))
          (dolist (file (org-agenda-files))
        (message (format "%s" file))
        (message (format "%s" (org-agenda-get-day-entries file date :scheduled)))))))
*** Eval error ***  Selecting deleted buffer
```

The message output shows:

```
(4 17 2019)
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/work.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/career.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/gcal.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/home.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/links.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/notes.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/journal.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/ideas.org
nil
(4 18 2019)
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/work.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/career.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/gcal.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/home.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/links.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/notes.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/journal.org
nil
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/ideas.org
nil
(4 19 2019)
/Users/dag/lib/dotfiles/dotemacs/org/work.org
```

So somehow on the third day things just stop working.   4/19 is the first day with anything scheduled, so that's suspicious.

What is the correct way to use `org-agenda-get-day-entries`?  Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Do you know how to use a [debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html#Debugging)? I would recommend [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug).

Comment: BTW, I ran your code locally with no problems, so I suspect something in your setup and/or your history is interfering. I would try it in a fresh emacs.

Comment: Yes, it does some to be something with my setup.  If I restart emacs it works.